# How do I get the path my script is running in?

Tags: scripting, python, path

I am writing a Quake 1 `.BSP` import script with python and I want to extract the textures from the `.BSP` so that the mesh can be textured. However, the textures are paletized (instead of a color, only an index into a palette is stored for each pixel) and the palette is not contained in the `.BSP`.

I'd like to include the palette in a file with my script, and load it from the script at run time. However, I don't know how to get the path to the palette file, so I can't load it. Is there a way to get the path my script is running in? I've tried using just the file name of the palette, but it didn't work.

p.s. I know I *could* store the palette in a python file, but I'd rather use the original `.PAL` format so that users can swap it for another palette if desired.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python has a built-in `__file__` global to access the path a script is running at. You can use it in your script by using this code snippet:

```
import os
script_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

WARNING: this will only work, i.e. will provide a correct path, only when passing python script using -P parameter, like this:

```
blender blenderfile.blend -P my_python_script.py
```

IF you would load that my_python_script.py into blender, then you will find that **file** has blenderfile.blend added as folder!