# Path to add-on before it is installed?

Tags: python, add-on, installation

When installing an add-on I would like to be able to extract the source path of the add-on with python, so I can use it as a default path in the ui to an included .exe file. How do I get the source path?

EDIT: I'm sorry for not being clear enough. The source path is for me where the add-on is located before it is installed(what I need), not where it is located when it is installed - I would call that the destination path(what I do not need).

Comment: how is this different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162366/get-location-of-the-py-source-file https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/639/how-do-i-get-the-path-my-script-is-running-in?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the path my script is running in?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/639/how-do-i-get-the-path-my-script-is-running-in)

Comment: i've added to the question, I hope it is more clear now?